# How to encode filter with phrase containing apostrophe

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am doing an API call with the "non-ascii apostrophe" in a filter:
**ga:eventaction=@Bev’s**

encoded it yields: **ga%3Aeventaction%3D%40Bev%E2%80%99s**

Here is my complete call:

```
GET /analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:xxxxxx&dimensions=ga:eventAction&metrics=ga:totalevents&sort=-ga:totalEvents&filters=ga%3Aeventaction%3D%40Bev%E2%80%99s&start-date=2018-01-19&end-date=2018-02-17&max-results=250 HTTP/1.1
```

However Google seems to be re-encoding it:
**ga:eventaction%3D@Bev%C3%A2%C2%80%C2%99s**

I have verified this works on the API Explorer Tool:

```
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3AeventAction&filters=ga%3Aeventaction%3D%40Bev%E2%80%99s
```

I have also tried passing it un-encoded and Google returns:
**ga%3Aeventaction%3D%40Bev?s**

I have attached a Fiddler screenshot.

How do I encode for the special character apostrophe?

[image]

Comment: How does it appear in your reports? Can you provide screenshots of that? While it may be playing with the encoding when transmitting the hit, it may be transforming and displaying the data correctly in GA.

Comment: @vinoaj - data in reports contain the apostrophe.  Also if done through the API Explorer it accepts the encoded string and displays it with apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

I think your expression should work after the below syntax error is fixed:

Change `ga:eventaction` to `ga:eventAction`

If that doesn't work, your next best bet is to use a regular expression

`ga:eventAction=~Bev\.s`